# CSS3 Font Face Not Working

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to use a custom font on my site but am having some trouble figuring out how to use the font face style to import the custom font.

I am using this as a reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AlexBrush';
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff') format(woff),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
.page-heading {
margin: 0;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 3.5em;
font-family: AlexBrush;
}
```

And my html:

```
<h1 class="page-heading">Page Header</h1>
```

The ../ in the url is to go one directory up and then into the fonts folder.

What am I missing ??

UPDATED CODE:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AlexBrush';
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    src: url('../fonts/alexbrush-regular-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Are the fonts loaded correctly? That is, have you checked your developer tools (Network tab) to see if they didn't give you an error.

Comment: I see so many wrong things, here is one of them `(woff)` should be  `('woff')` You really should follow the tutorial again and do it right this time.

Comment: `font-family: AlexBrush;` should be `font-family: 'AlexBrush';`

Comment: Okay I have updated the code, I still cant seem to get the font to apply correctly

Comment: If I have a look in the network tab of the developer tools I dont see any of the font files, does this mean they were not found ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was that I had include the "src" property for each line, even though lines were separated by commas rather than ";"